# Too slow data fetching in React, leading to annot read properties of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a problem with data displaying. Probably the JSX content is rendering too fast before data is actually fetched from API and that causing the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

I checked with `console.log`; sometimes it's fetching, sometimes not. Also, when I comment out this `{concerts[1].name}`, then data is loaded and populated. However, when I run it like in the example below, data is not populating, and I am getting errors.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const ConcertNewest = () => {
  const [concerts, setConcerts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadConcerts = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("/data/concerts");

      setConcerts(response.data);
    };
    loadConcerts();
  }, []);

  console.log("concerts: " + concerts.length);
  return (
    <show>
      <h1>Newest concerts </h1>
      <div>
        <div className="card">
          <img src="" style={{ width: 100 }} />
          <div className="card-text">
            <h4> {concerts[1].name}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </show>
  );
};
```

Comment: When your component initially mounts you are setting `concerts` to `[]`. So there is no `concerts[1]` on the initial render. As `fetch` is async, it will **never** be finished before the inital render. So you have to take care of that for yourself ... Not just because of asynchronous code, but imagine what happens if your call returns an empty array, because there are no concerts scheduled ...  And BTW `concerts[1]` accesses the *second*  element of that array ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside `useEffect` runs after the JSX is rendered. That's by design. So you are ending up with `concerts[1].name` while `concerts` is still empty.

A common way to tackle this is to show some loading indicator while the data is being fetched, like so, for example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const ConcertNewest = () => {
  const [concerts, setConcerts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadConcerts = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("/data/concerts");

      setConcerts(response.data);
    };
    loadConcerts();
  }, []);

  if (!concerts.length) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
  return (
    <show>
      <h1>Newest concerts </h1>
      <div>
        <div className="card">
          <img src="" style={{ width: 100 }} />
          <div className="card-text">
            <h4> {concerts[1].name}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </show>
  );
};
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. So easy solution. I was afraid i will end up searching for answer for the next couple of hours