# Next.JS Unhandled Runtime Error when refresh page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I am implementing a page using a dynamic ID and I use Tanstack React-Query to query the data, and I notice that everytime I refresh the page having an ID as a URL I got the following message:

`Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'image')`

Code example below:

```
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;

    //? Data Query
    // Fetch User information
    const fetchGetUserInformation = async () => {
     try {
       const response = await fetch(`/api/user/${id}`, {
         method: 'GET',
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
         }

         const dataJSON = await response.json();
         return await dataJSON;
       } catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
       }
    };

    const { isLoading, isError, data, error } = useQuery(
    ['userData'],
    fetchGetUserInformation
    );

    return (
     <div className='mt-3'>
       <img
         className='w-36 h-36 rounded ml-2'
         src={data.image}
         alt='Profile image'
       />
     </div>
    );
```

To notice that in this example it says `reading 'image'` but other parts of the code use the first payload I  use such as name or username, is like if on refresh the page delete the retrieved data. What it could be the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too slow data fetching in React, leading to annot read properties of undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275872/too-slow-data-fetching-in-react-leading-to-annot-read-properties-of-undefined-e)

Answer (score 1):

you throw an error inside the fetch function and then you catch it, and log it, check the error on the console, maybe no data were sent, so you cannot read data.image if the data is equal to null,
otherwise, add this before your return to wait for your data to come then showcase it.

```
if(isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>
if(isError) return <div>{error}</div>
```